# Keyup event handler that focuses on next element loses just-entered charater if typing too fast

Tags: jquery

I have a web page with 16 textboxes arranged in a 4x4 grid. The idea is that a user will type precisely one character into each textbox (specifically, a letter). You can see this page online at http://fuzzylogicinc.net/Boggle/EnterBoardClientSide.aspx

What I want to happen is the following:

- When the page loads the upper left textbox is focused
- Typing a letter in the textbox should enter that letter and then automatically set focus to the next textbox in the grid
- If the user selects a textbox (either via the mouse or by Shift-Tabbing back to a previous textbox) the entry in the textbox should be selected so that they can just type the new letter to overwrite the old one.

I've got this working for the most part, but have one vexing problem - namely, if a user types the letters too fast, some textboxes are left empty, as if the code that whisks the user to the next textbox occurs before the browser has a chance to actually commit the letter to the textbox that had focus (if that makes any sense). If you visit my live demo and start typing at a decent rate, you'll see that some textboxes are left blank.

My JavaScript, which can be seen it its entirety [here](http://fuzzylogicinc.net/Boggle/Scripts/BoggleScriptAJax.js), has the following code for selecting/focusing/moving to the next textbox:

```
$("input.BoggleGridCell")
    .focus(function () {
        $(this).select();
    })
    .keyup(function (event) {
        var code = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);

        if ((code >= 65 && code <= 90) || (code >= 97 && code <= 122)) {
            var currentId = $(this).attr('id');

            var leftDigit = currentId.substring(1, 2);
            var rightDigit = currentId.substring(2, 3);
            if (leftDigit != 3 || rightDigit != 3) {
                if (rightDigit == 3) {
                    rightDigit = 0;
                    leftDigit++;
                }
                else {
                    rightDigit++;
                }

                var moveToId = 'c' + leftDigit + rightDigit;
                var newCell = document.getElementById(moveToId);
                if (newCell)
                    newCell.focus();
            }
            else {
                $("#solve").focus();
            }
        }
    });
```

Note that all my textboxes in the grid have a CSS class of `BoggleGridCell`. Each textbox in the grid has an `id` of the form `cXY`, where X is the row number and Y is the column number. I have a bit of code in the `keyup` event handler that examines this X and Y value of the current textbox's `id` to determine the next textbox to focus.

What's going on here? My intuition is that when typing at a sufficient pace that the `keyup` event for the first key press hasn't completed by the time the `keyup` event for the subsequent key press is raised.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured a workaround... I ended up using jQuery's `keypress` event plus JavaScript's `setTimeout` function. Here's the final code that appears to work as expected in IE 8, FF 3, and Google Chrome.

```
$("input.BoggleGridCell")
    .focus(function () {
        $(this).select();
    })
    .keypress(function (event) {
        var code = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);

        if ((code >= 65 && code <= 90) || (code >= 97 && code <= 122)) {
            var currentId = $(this).attr('id');

            var leftDigit = currentId.substring(1, 2);
            var rightDigit = currentId.substring(2, 3);
            if (leftDigit != 3 || rightDigit != 3) {
                if (rightDigit == 3) {
                    rightDigit = 0;
                    leftDigit++;
                }
                else {
                    rightDigit++;
                }

                setTimeout(function () {
                    var moveToId = 'c' + leftDigit + rightDigit;
                    var newCell = document.getElementById(moveToId);
                    if (newCell)
                        newCell.focus();
                }, 1);
            }
            else {
                setTimeout('$("#solve").focus();', 1);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

It may be that the problem is caused by the user overlapping their key presses as they type.  To see what I mean, hold down one key, and press another at the same time.  This appears to have the same effect that you are talking about.

EDIT: From this it seems that the keyUp event for the second key fires, then the keyUp event for the first key fires.  However, the disrupted order prevents the letter from the second key press from being inserted into the appropriate input.

You could get around this by adding a keyDown event to check first that there isn't a key currently being held.

```
var pressed=0;
$("input.BoggleGridCell")

.focus(function () {

  $(this).select();

})
.keydown(function(event){
  var code = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
  if ((code >= 65 && code <= 90) || (code >= 97 && code <= 122)) {
    pressed=code;
  }
})      
.keyup(function (event) {
  if(pressed!=0){
    var code = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if ((code >= 65 && code <= 90) || (code >= 97 && code <= 122)) {
     //Your Code Here
    }
  }
  pressed=0;
}
});
```

Comment: Your solution sort of works. If I type quickly it doesn't me skip -past- a textbox, leaving it empty, but if I type two characters in close succession it leaves me locked on the first textbox, until I type slower (if that makes sense).

Comment: Yes, I can see what you mean.  keyup generally tends to result in a slightly sticky feeling interface in my experience.  The combination of keyPress and a timeout hadn't occurred to me.  Nice App by the way!

Answer (score 0):

The browser DOM and events are notoriously bad at consistent and predictable performance - particularly when handling keyboard or mouse events. My suggestion would be to re-architect the idea somewhat... otherwise you will just end up chasing issues like this for a long time.

After looking at your demo, I am not quite sure what to recommend. Having a single text box that handles the input (it could even be invisible/hidden) and just dispatch the events from there - maybe hooking the 'change' event rather than an individual key press would probably be more reliable, though it might be too much of a departure from what you are trying to do. And it certainly would add additional complexity to allow for editing individual cells (hooking the blur event).

Another idea I had was to make the keyup event return as fast as possible - wrap the majority of the body into an anonymous function that is passed into a setTimeOut() invocation. It would probably be beneficial to precompute the next cell in advance as well so you could skip over all that logic. I don't know as though that would solve the performance problem though... warning I didn't test this code - I present it as an idea. There may be a problem with the closure around the $(this) call particularly.

```
$("input.BoggleGridCell")
.focus(function () {
    $(this).select();
})
.keyup(function (event) {
    var code = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if ((code >= 65 && code <= 90) || (code >= 97 && code <= 122)) {
        setTimeOut(function(){
          var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
          var leftDigit = currentId.substring(1, 2);
          var rightDigit = currentId.substring(2, 3);
          if (leftDigit != 3 || rightDigit != 3) {
              if (rightDigit == 3) {
                  rightDigit = 0;
                  leftDigit++;
              } else {
                rightDigit++;
              }
              var moveToId = 'c' + leftDigit + rightDigit;
              var newCell = document.getElementById(moveToId);
              if (newCell)
                newCell.focus();
          } else {
            $("#solve").focus();
        }, 1);
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried your approach, but it resulted in the same issue. I sort of took your idea, but used the keypress event instead (see my answer) and it appears to work as expected.